# Find max of $S = x\sin^2\angle A + y\sin^2\angle B + z\sin^2\angle C$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ are positive constants. $A$, $B$, $C$ are three angles of the triangle. Prove that $$S = x \sin^2 A + y \sin^2 B + z \sin^2 C \leq \dfrac{\left(yz+zx+xy\right)^2}{4xyz}$$
and find when it holds equality

Comment: are $x,y,z$ positive numbers?

Comment: i would use the Lagrange Multiplier method

Comment: There is an inequality $x \sin^2 A + y \sin^2 B + z \sin^2 C \leq \dfrac{\left(yz+zx+xy\right)^2}{4xyz}$ (which follows from Theorem 2 in http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h69200p590661 , also mirrored at http://mathoverflow.net/a/62906 , after the substitution of $yz, zx, xy$ for $x, y, z$). The question is now whether it can achieve equality. (Which, by the way, is also an issue with the Lagrange-multiplier approach.)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This is an intricate problem, since not only the *value* of $S_{\max}$ is changing with the values of the parameters $x$, $y$, $z$, but also the global extremal situation.

*Claim:* If $0<2x<y\leq z$ then $S_{\max}=y+z$.

*Proof:* If one of the angles is $>{\pi\over2}$, e.g., $\alpha\leq\beta<{\pi\over2}<\gamma$,  it is possible to enlarge $S$ by replacing  $\alpha$, $\beta$,$\gamma$ with $$\alpha':=\alpha+\gamma-{\pi\over2}, \quad \beta':=\beta,\quad \gamma':={\pi\over2}\ .$$
It follows that we may assume $0\leq\alpha\leq\beta\leq\gamma\leq{\pi\over2}$, in this order. Write $\beta:={\pi\over2}-\beta'$, $\>\gamma:={\pi\over2}-\gamma'$, $\alpha:=\beta'+\gamma'$. Then $S$ appears as
$$S=\sin^2(\beta'+\gamma') x+(1-\sin^2\beta')y+(1-\sin^2\gamma')z\ .$$
Now by Schwarz' inequality
$$\sin(\beta'+\gamma')=\cos\gamma'\sin\beta'+\cos\beta'\sin\gamma'\leq\sqrt{\cos^2\gamma'+\cos^2\beta'} \sqrt{\sin^2\beta'+\sin^2\gamma'}\ ,$$
so that
$$\sin^2(\beta'+\gamma')\leq 2(\sin^2\beta'+\sin^2\gamma')\ .$$
It follows that
$$S\leq y+z-(y-2x)\sin^2\beta'-(z-2x)\sin^2\gamma'\leq y+z$$
with equality iff $\beta'=\gamma'=0$.$\quad\square$

On the other hand, if $x=y=z=1$, then $\alpha=0$, $\beta=\gamma={\pi\over2}$ leads to $S=2$, whereas
$\alpha=\beta=\gamma={\pi\over3}$ produce $S={9\over4}$. This shows that there is a "phase transition" where the morphology of the extremal situation changes.

Comment: "pretty obvious" is the new "left to the reader"? ;)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: It was indeed not obvious...